# Sql - delete all rows of a column containing special characters(not alphanumeric)

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanna delete all the rows of a `table`
where `column` contains **special characters** such as `@#$_&-+()/*'';!?~|•√π÷¶∆£¢¥^°={}\%©™℅[]`
Basically all of it where all the elements are not alphabet or a number.

Comment: I wanna delete those who are'nt alphanumeric @CodeCaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codecaster gave you the path to the solution. Decompose to get it.

You have this :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
```

Which returns all rows that contains only alphanumeric chars

If you want to delete all other rows, you can do :

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT ID FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
)
```

or negate the regex :

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE column NOT REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
```